# Getting USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED ERROR for OTA_AirRulesRQ

Tags: soap, sabre

I am using **BinarySecurityToken** for **OTA_AirRulesRQ**, but I am getting **USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED**. I used the same token for **BargainFinderMaxRQ** and it worked. Is it some problem with the SOAP request I am sending or access to this method is not authorized form my PCC ?

Also I am able to hold PNR and Issue ticket with same credentials

Please Suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact the API helpdesk providing your credentials

Answer (score 0):

Do you point it to the according endpoint. E.g. getting creds from prod/testing and using it in prod/testing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the message you are trying to send including headers.  You can block out Pcc information, but it would help to see the message.  It may be something simple you are overlooking and at the very least I could duplicate the call on my test bench and try to to duplicate the issue.